# Why data migration (D to H) started before kernel launch?

Tags: cuda

Following is the result of `nvvp` profiling result for the CUDA managed memory based code:

[image]

**QUESTION:** As seen in the screenshot above, the data migration (D to H) starts even before the kernel is launched. Though the size of the first Data Migration block (that started before kernel launch) is quite small (approx. 450kb) as compared to the total data (approx. 4 MB) that needs to be transferred. So, what is this data exactly? How can Data Migration (D to H) taken place before launch?

**My Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include "cuda_runtime.h"

// CUDA kernel to add elements of two arrays
__global__
void add(int n, float* x, float* y)
{
    int index = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int stride = blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
    for (int i = index; i < n; i += stride)
        y[i] = x[i] + y[i];
}


int RunManagedVersion()
{
    int N = 1 << 20;
    float* x, * y;

    // Allocate Unified Memory -- accessible from CPU or GPU
    cudaMallocManaged(&x, N * sizeof(float));
    cudaMallocManaged(&y, N * sizeof(float));

    // initialize x and y arrays on the host
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        x[i] = 1.0f;
        y[i] = 2.0f;
    }

    // Launch kernel on 1M elements on the GPU
    int blockSize = 256;
    int numBlocks = (N + blockSize - 1) / blockSize;
    add << <numBlocks, blockSize >> > (N, x, y);

    // Wait for GPU to finish before accessing on host
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    // Check for errors (all values should be 3.0f)
    float maxError = 0.0f;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        maxError = fmax(maxError, fabs(y[i] - 3.0f));

    std::cout << "Max error: " << maxError << std::endl;

    // Free memory
    cudaFree(x);
    cudaFree(y);

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    //RunUnmanagedVersion();

    RunManagedVersion();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The profiler does not localize this type of D->H transfer to a specific point in time.

Instead it breaks the timeline up into roughly fixed time segments, and determines if any D->H transfers occurred during that segment. If so, the segment will be reported as having a D->H transfer "in it", and the segment will be color-coded to indicate the relative "density" of transfers within that segment.

Therefore, the beginning of the green bar you are referring to is not necessarily the instant at which a D->H transfer was occurring, instead it is the start of a measurement segment during which some D->H transfer activity occurred.

Since that green bar segment extends well after kernel completion, it is evidently accounting for D->H transfer activity after the kernel is finished, which is expected.

(One could ask a similar question about the H->D line and the blue bar immediately before, during, and after the kernel launch.  Clearly there is no need for H->D activity *after* the kernel launch.  Again, the activity is measured and reported according to fixed time segments.)

By the way (for future readers), the data migration (D->H) that is well in advance of the kernel launch was explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70160723/1695960).

Comment: Thanks, I thought that too that the timeline is not an exact representation of the actual start/stop of data transfer but wanted to confirm that I am not missing something.